# Razor chart recommendation

Tags: c#, .net, razor, charts

I am currently doing an mvc3 razor project and I need some charts.

I will need to blend bars and lines in a single chart or/and have multiple dataseries.
I was just wondering which charts you guys use. Price is a factor but I would like to hear some real world usage before trying out to many of the thousands of the charts available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) before and find the [API](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/) very nice to use,  also as its essentially a Jquery plugin using a JSON result in your Razor view would integrate nicely.

Comment: Thanks @Jota and you all for the recommendations, I tried Google and Telerik (witch are the microsoft ones on steroid's) but found that HightCharts are best suited for my needs. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

We're currently using [Google Chart Tools](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start.html). It uses HTML5/SVG technology (adopting VML for old IE versions) so it's all rendered on the browser. The JavaScript API is really powerful yet pretty simple to understand and very flexible allowing you to customize almost everything from the data to the presentation. Because it's all rendered in browser it also offers very nice and clean animations on mouse-over and mouse-click.

You've detailed [documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/chart/interactive/docs/) for each type of chart.

Check the default charts [here](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery.html). Also available are the [Additional Charts](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/chart/interactive/docs/more_charts.html) which are compliant with [DataTable](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/chart/interactive/docs/datatables_dataviews.html) protocol (a way to represent charts data through JavaScript) and are *somehow* approved by Google.

It's **free**!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ASP.Net chart controls in an MVC Razor project, although not quite as easily as it is in `.aspx` pages.

See [Charts in ASP.Net MVC 2 With Drill-Down!](http://geekswithblogs.net/DougLampe/archive/2011/01/23/charts-in-asp.net-mvc-2-with-drill-down.aspx) for an example using `.aspx` syntax that can easily be converted to Razor syntax.